# JavaFX 2.0 FXML resource loading error

Tags: resources, javafx-2, fxml

```
@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            stage = primaryStage;
            gotoLogin();
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    enter code here
    public User getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public boolean userLogging(String userId, String password){
        if (Authenticator.validate(userId, password)) {
            loggedUser = User.of(userId);
            gotoProfile();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void userLogout(){
        loggedUser = null;
        gotoLogin();
    }

    private void gotoProfile() {
        try {
            replaceSceneContent("../skinFolder/fxml/profile.fxml");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void gotoLogin() {
        try {
            replaceSceneContent("../skinFolder/fxml/login.fxml");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private Parent replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
        Parent page = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource(fxml), null, new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        Scene scene = stage.getScene();
        if (scene == null) {
            scene = new Scene(page, 700, 450);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(App.class.getResource("../skinFolder/css/defaultSkin.css").toExternalForm());
            stage.setScene(scene);
        } else {
            stage.getScene().setRoot(page);
        }
        stage.sizeToScene();
        return page;
    }}
```

So i am trying to use the sample of the FXML Login example, only i give other way for the fxml. And in the fxml files i gave the way to the controller.

```
The log shows those errors:

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at Main.App.replaceSceneContent(App.java:115)
at Main.App.gotoProfile(App.java:100)
at Main.App.userLogging(App.java:86)
at skinFolder.controllers.LoginController.processLogin(LoginController.java:28)
```

Login Controller Class

```
public class LoginController {
    @FXML private TextField userId;
    @FXML private PasswordField password;
    @FXML private Label errorMessage;

    @FXML protected void processLogin() {
        if(!App.getInstance().userLogging(userId.getText(), password.getText())){
            errorMessage.setText("Username/password combination is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the line 28 is:

```
if(!App.getInstance().userLogging(userId.getText(), password.getText())){
```

I mention that the fxml files are in another folder the Main file folder. I don't get why i get this error when i am using the example gave by the Oracle, but with another folder structure!

My app folder structure:

- Main
- Model
- Security
- skinFolder - css
- skinFolder - fxml
- skinFolder - controllers

Here is the profile.fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="Profile" styleClass="profile" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="skinFolder.controllers.ProfileController">
   <children>
    <Button maxHeight="2.0" text="Update" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="168.0" fx:id="update" onAction="#processUpdate"/>
    <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="77.0" text="Please review your profile data." fx:id="message" />
    <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="123.0" text="User:" />
    <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="224.0" text="Phone:" />
    <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="173.0" text="Email:" />
    <TextField editable="false" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="120.0" maxWidth="2.0" minHeight="30.0" minWidth="215.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="215.0" fx:id="user" />
    <TextField editable="true" layoutX="149.0" layoutY="171" maxWidth="2.0" minHeight="30.0" minWidth="215.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="215.0" fx:id="email" />
    <TextField layoutX="149.0" layoutY="224" maxWidth="2.0" minHeight="30.0" minWidth="215.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="215.0" fx:id="phone" />
    <CheckBox layoutX="402" layoutY="120.0" text="Subscribed to NewsLetter" fx:id="subscribed" />
    <Separator layoutX="380" layoutY="110" prefHeight="155" orientation="vertical"/>
    <Hyperlink layoutY="24.0" text="logout" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="52.0" fx:id="logout" onAction="#processLogout"/>
    <Button disable="true" maxHeight="2" maxWidth="2.0" text="Continue" defaultButton="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="52.0" fx:id="Button" onAction="#processLogout"/>
    <Label layoutX="150.0" layoutY="401.0" opacity="0.0" text="Profile  successfully updated!" fx:id="success" />
    <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="284.0" text="Address:" />
    <TextArea maxHeight="2.0" maxWidth="2.0" minHeight="85.0" minWidth="448.0" prefHeight="85.0" prefWidth="448.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="69.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="149.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="52.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="289.0" fx:id="address" />
  </children>
  <styleClass>
    <String fx:value="profile" />
  </styleClass>
  <properties>
    <elementLockSel>
      <Boolean fx:value="true" />
    </elementLockSel>
  </properties>
</AnchorPane>
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: post the whole exception, please. With given parameters your code should work.

Comment: Hi Sergey, here are more details. Maybe you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to [your previous question (JavaFX 2.0 load fxml files from subfolder fails)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10411164/682495). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412508/682495). Same here for `processUpdate` action.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `profile.fxml` file. You didn't include error description in stacktrace but most probably you have wrong or misspelled attribute tag in there.

Please, add `profile.fxml` and full stack trace to the post if you need more help.

Comment: I edited my question, that was the stack error! The error seems to be from the lines who haves onAction inside like: <Button maxHeight="2.0" text="Update" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="168.0" fx:id="update" onAction="#processUpdate"/>