# Error Compiling JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm new to `java`, I'm trying to build a `JavaFX` Application on eclipse using `e(fx)clipse` by following a [tutorial](http://edu.makery.ch/blog/2012/11/16/javafx-tutorial-addressapp-1/) and did exactly the same, the application is very simple, when I try to compile it I get bunch of errors which I don't even understand :

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2021)
    at ch.makery.address.controler.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    ... 1 more
```

please can you tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: This question is answered already:
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13806031/2072528)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error loading fxml files from a folder other than the bin folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785919/error-loading-fxml-files-from-a-folder-other-than-the-bin-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the location of the `FXML` file in your [loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html), be sure that you are providing the correct [PATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to your `FXML` file.

**PS:** [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is the best choice for a `JavaFX` beginner, start [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).

Comment: I got it fixed thanks for the help, concerning NetBeans, indeed it is, but I'm kinda forced to use eclipse, any nice starting up tutorials for JavaFx on Eclipse, I would be tankful

Comment: Oueld Kara is weld 9ahba, I will update my answer later for more tutorial links.

Comment: Haha I see you got What I meant by "forced to use eclipse", I'm even afraid he won't be pleased by me using JavaFx, thx for the tutorial links anyway