# Cannot include FXML file in another folder

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an FXML file that I'd like to include in another. The problem is, it resides in another folder. Now when I assign the full path as:

```
<fx:include source="/applicationName/folder1/folder2/anFXMLFile.fxml"/>
```

the parent fxml file sees it and Nebeans even allows me to CTRL+click to open the file for editing.

However, when I double click the Parent file scene builder won't open it.

The error I get when attempting to load it in Scene Builder is this:

```
Error loading file       
'C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Application/src/application/staff/view/NewStaff.fxml'.
 C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Application\src\application\staff\view\NewStaff.fxml:23: error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```

I'm really not sure what's going on.

My motivation is this: The included FXML files represent things like "personal info", "address", forms which I can re-use with multiple entities like people, staff, locations, etc.

By having the FXML files in one place and including them in other fxml files I was hoping for some code-reuse. That's all. I can keep all the included fxml in the same folder as the parent and it works fine.

Please help!

Comment: Anyone? I'd really like to get this one to work. Would in-clutter my code by quite a significant margin!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question: [Error loading fxml files from a folder other than the bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785919/error-loading-fxml-files-from-a-folder-other-than-the-bin-folder) is about the same problem.  Start with what's there and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Custom.fxml"));
```